# detect duplicate character in string

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char

I am doing the exercises in the Cracking The Coding Interview book and I am trying to determine if there is a duplicate character in a string. I am using the ArrayList data structure. My method is of return type Boolean, which returns true if there is a duplicate and returns false if there is no duplicate character. I added a third return statement so the program would compile but it always returns false.

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuestionOneCrackingCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcdefga";
        ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
        c.add(s);

        System.out.print(check(c));
    }

    public static boolean check(ArrayList<String> g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < g.size(); j++) {
                if (g.get(i) == g.get(j)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `if (...) { return true; } else { return false; }` can be simplified to `return ...;`.

Comment: I would recommend doing something even easier: look inside the `String`, use a `char` variable for the current char and do a search from the current position to the last or from the current position to the first. This saves time and it's easier to code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think that's the correct dupe - even if he switched to `.equals()` it wouldn't work - the real problem is rather that he's expecting `c.add(s)` to split the String into characters when it's actually just going to result in a single-item list of the original String, which won't even get compared to anything. And if he was actually comparing chars, `==` would be correct

Comment: @CupawnTae well yes, there are more problems with this implementation. I'll reopen the question. Please provide an answer making use of this now non-dup as well.

Comment: @CupawnTae OP's comparing `String`s, not `char`s, check the parameter: `ArrayList<String> g` and its usage: `g.get(i)`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I realize that, but fixing the algorithm (as opposed to replacing it with a better one) would result in comparing chars, so the parameter would presumably change too

Comment: @CupawnTae let's talk about your proposed solution, not over a possible solution on the fly trying to reuse this code.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't proposing a solution, just pointing out that it's not really a dupe of comparing strings, but for example `check(CharSequence g)` ...  `if(g.charAt(i) == g.charAt(j))` would preserve the spirit of the algorithm while fixing the specific issue

Comment: What about `"test".matches(".*(.).*\\1.*")`

Comment: @CupawnTae yes, it will. And that's why I'm asking (for a third time) if you please could post an answer :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well up until about 10 seconds ago I couldn't because it was closed!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using the String data structure and it is working. :)

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8, you could do it like this:

```
public static boolean check(CharSequence checkString)
{
  return checkString.length() != checkString.chars().distinct().count();
}
```

I.e. if the number of distinct characters in the string is not the same as the total number of characters, you know there's a duplicate. It's not necessarily the most efficient way, but it's succinct.

Answer (score 5):

You're not separating your string into characters, you're creating a single-element list containing your string. Without making big changes to your algorithm, you could do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcdefga";

    System.out.print(check(s));
}

public static boolean check(CharSequence g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < g.length(); j++) {
            if (g.charAt(i) == g.charAt(j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that the first `return false;` was also incorrect because it would stop the algorithm from continuing past the first comparison.

As an aside, when you *are* comparing Strings, you should use `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution compares string references in a list. The list itself contains only one String.

Try the following:

```
// check one string for duplicate chars
public static boolean check(String checkString)
{
    // result flag
    boolean foundDuplicate = false;
    // get string length
    int stringLength = checkString.length();
    // create a set for all found characters (max size is number
    // of characters in the string to check
    Set<Character> characters = new HashSet<>(stringLength);
    // loop all characters in string
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        // construct a object (may be use internal JDK cache)
        Character c = Character.valueOf(checkString.charAt(i));
        // check if character is already found
        if (characters.contains(c))
        {
            // yes, set result to TRUE
            foundDuplicate = true;
            // break the loop
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // not found, add char to set
            characters.add(c);
        }
    }
    return foundDuplicate;
}
```

This is limited by the string length and the heap size. But I assume that all UTF-8 characters may fit into heap.

@Maarten Bodewes You are right. The check can be simplified to:

```
        // add character to set and check result
        if (!characters.add(c))
        {
            // returned false: character already exists
            foundDuplicate = true;
            // break the loop
            break;
        }
        // no else necessary
```

Comment: You can simply use the return value of `add`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the results of my version of your code.

```
abcdefga true
abcdefgh false
abcdefdh true
```

1. I modified the check parameter to take a single String.  There's no need for a List of Strings.
2. In the check method, you can exit once one pair of characters match.  You have to test the entire string before you can say there are no matching characters.
3. The first for loop can stop at the second to last character.  The second for loop will get the last character.
4. Since I'm comparing char values, I use the ==.  If I were comparing String values, I would use the .equals method.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class QuestionOneCrackingCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcdefga";
        System.out.println(s + " " + check(s));
        s = "abcdefgh";
        System.out.println(s + " " + check(s));
        s = "abcdefdh";
        System.out.println(s + " " + check(s));
    }

    public static boolean check(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (s.length() - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

My participation:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check("abcdefga"));                    // true
        System.out.println(check("noduplicate"));                 // false
        System.out.println(check("withduplicate"));               // true
        System.out.println(check("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));  // false
        System.out.println(check("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz")); // true
    }

    /**@brief Check if a String contains duplicated characters.
     * Strong expectation for the string: The String must only contains
     * lowercase alpha characters (ie. in [a-z])
     * @returns true if a char is present more than once */
    public static boolean check(String str) {
        int presentChars = 0; // will store the table of already found characters
        int l = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            int offset = c - 'a';             // a=0, b=1, ... z=25
            int mask = 1 << offset;
            if ((presentChars& mask) != 0) {  // Oh! Char already tagged as found
                return true;                  // No need to process further, bye!
            }
            presentChars|= mask;              // Tag the current char as present
        }
        return false;                         // No duplicate
    }

}
```

My goal with this code is to minimize the complexity. This algorithm is in O(N) on the worst case. Also, the memory footprint of the function is very low: only one `int` is really necessary (`presentChars`) even if I use more in order to improve readability =)

Downside of this code: there is a big prerequisite on the inputed string. I've detailed this on the comments, but it works only with characters in the [a-z] range.

I hope it's helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a String instead of ArrayList.
2. Do not return if the comparison fails, you need to keep searching and not return false, this is why it always returns false.
3. Even then this is not the most optimized solution, try thinking about bucket sort and how it fits this problem. This will make your solution run in O(N) instead of O(N^2).

```
public static boolean check(String g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < g.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < g.length(); j++) {
            if (g.charAt(i) == (g.charAt(j))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a table to count how many times a character is repeated, if a character appeared more of one time then return true, the code in the worst case is O(n)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test ="abdefghijklmnoPQRSTUVWXYZa";
    System.out.println(isThereAnyCharacterRepeated(test));
}


public static boolean isThereAnyCharacterRepeated(String str){

    int repeatedCharacters[] = new int[255];
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        int index=(int)str.charAt(i);
        repeatedCharacters[index]++;
        if(repeatedCharacters[index]>1)return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```